# How to export pixi.application as json?

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, pixi.js

I have used pixi canvas.

```
var app = new PIXI.Application(800, 800, { backgroundColor: 0xffffff});
```

and i have added one image to canvas.

```
var texture2 = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("http://192.168.2.26:8000/videoeditor/img/boy.png");
var moveSprite2 = new PIXI.Sprite(texture2);
moveSprite2.anchor.x = 0.5;
moveSprite2.anchor.y = 0.5;
moveSprite2.width = 300;
moveSprite2.height = 500;
moveSprite2.position.set(500, 400);
app.stage.addChild(moveSprite2);
```

How to export app as json for remix the pixi canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not answer your question directly.

You can use `pixiAPP.renderer.view.toDataURL()` to get the raw data of the pixi canvas.

If you assign that raw data to an `img` tag's `src` for example, you can reproduce the canvas' content.